# Trying to install Cython: no setup.py in downloaded Cython directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I downloaded the newest Cython release from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cython/#downloads. I'm working in Python 3.5.1 on a Mac so I downloaded

`Cython-0.26.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`

I unzipped it and entered the /Cython directory, but there is no setup.py in the directory. When I try to run `python3 setup.py install` anyway I get the following error:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

It doesn't seem to be looking in the /Cython directory I am in, but there is also no setup.py in that directory.

Not sure what's going on, I can't seem to find anyone else having this issue.

I've install python3 using homebrew.

Comment: Anaconda comes with Cython and there is an installer for Mac.

Comment: The file you have downloaded is a "wheel". It contains the package in a form that is ready to install by the software "pip". Have you tried to install cython via homebrew? This will probably be easier.

Comment: Oh, great, yeah, homebrew was easy. Thanks.

Comment: As a note, I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04, which was solved in the same way, by pip installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you downloaded is a wheel file that should be installed using `pip`. The wheel file does not include the `setup.py` script which is required to build the package but is not used when installing wheels. First check you are using correct `pip` command (you need one for python 3.5), this is usually `pip3.5` or `pip3` command:

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

To install `cython` from the downloaded wheel, issue

```
$ pip3 install path/to/downloaded.whl
```

Or simply issue

```
$ pip3 install cython
```

as `pip` will download the latest package wheel for you. Since you installed python 3.5 via Homebrew, you probably have to switch to the user you use to install packages with Homebrew or the installation with `pip` will fail.

Note that, although suggested in the comments, it is not advised to install `cython` package via `brew install`:

```
$ brew info cython
...
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into 
/usr/local,
because this formula is mainly used internally by other formulae.
Users are advised to use `pip` to install cython.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised the documentation does not have this explanation. How did you know it should be pip3 not pip as the documentation says?
http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html

Comment: Glad I could help! I guessed `pip3` because the OP mentioned he uses `python3.5`, so its package manager should be accessible via `pip3.5` or `pip3`, depending on the distribution. On Unix, `python2.7` is still the default python version, so `pip` usually refers to `pip2.7`. You can check the version on your machine by issuing `pip --version`.